# Where can I find the list of possible values for the service and resource type parts in AWS ARN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm searching for a list of all possible values for the service and resource type parts in AWS ARN.
The two parts are explained in the documentation:   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html
If there is some API I can run and get the list in json or other data format, it would be even better.

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> a list of all possible values for the service and resource type parts in an AWS ARN

The AWS [**Service Authorization Reference**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/reference.html) is what you're looking for, specifically: [*Actions, resources, and condition keys for AWS services*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html).

> The Service Authorization Reference provides a **list of the actions, resources, and condition keys that are supported by each AWS service**. You can specify actions, resources, and condition keys in AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) policies to manage access to AWS resources.

---

> If there is some API I can run and get the list in json or other data format, it would be even better.

Unfortunately, no API exists for this info as it's not a service but more of a documentation reference.

Answer (score 3):

Found https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/js/policies.js if you want a json file with all services and action to process progrematically.

Answer (score 2):

There is no central reference of "all possible values" of an ARN.

Each AWS Service has resources that use ARNs. Since the address space is divided into 'services', each service can create its own resource references (eg Amazon EC2 would have `instance` and `volume`).

Comment: Thanks John, I know that. But still, I would expect AWS to document the supported services in the service part and for each service what resource types are supported. Currently, I'm more interested in the options possible in IAM policy statements resources fields.

Comment: Ah -- you should have said so! For a list of IAM Actions and Permissions, see: [Actions, resources, and condition keys for AWS services - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html)